# Is it correct to assign a CVSS to a misconfiguration?

Tags: vulnerability, configuration, cvss

This morning, talking to a colleague, we were discussing the correction of assigning a CVSS to a bad configuration. Specifically, we were discussing whether using HTTP instead of HTTPS should have an associated vector.

From my point of view, a configuration is not a vulnerability, in the sense that it is not a software or hardware defect and therefore can have an associated risk factor but not a vector or a score derived from it.

What is your opinion?

Comment: HTTP is not a "misconfiguration". It is a configuration.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments, your HTTP example would not be a misconfiguration. But, certain configs can result in or amplify vulnerabilities. For example, if a endpoint on a web app does not enforce authentication (when it should), this would be labeled as a “security misconfiguration vulnerability” on a Pentesting report because it allows an user or attacker to bypass security controls and also rated as High risk.

So I would answer yes, configurations can be a vulnerability because it can expose you to attack just like any other type of vulnerability.

And you can assign a cvss score to a configuration,  but if it makes sense is another question...

Comment: I'm partially agree with you.

I think so, if you want you can assign a CVSS vector.

However, and under my understanding, a vulnerability is kind of a bug or flaw in a HW or SW product; not changing a default configuration or choosing a less secure option is not, (although it is a security risk that must be taken into account).

Using a CVSS vector therefore,  it doesn't make sense at all, in my opinion, while using a risk factor does. 

Regarding a pentesting report, i would categorized that kind of findings  under another category which would group default or bad configurations...

Comment: Part of my argument was based on the content of this article:
https://avleonov.com/2019/01/28/what-is-a-vulnerability-and-what-is-not/

Answer (score 0):

Vulnerability - is a weakness which can be exploited by a threat actor, such as an attacker, to perform unauthorized actions within a computer system.

If the HTTP vs HTTPS can be leveraged in your system in a way that the previous statement is true you have a vulnerability.

You can use the CVSS calculator to build your criticality...
https://www.first.org/cvss/calculator/3.1

If you wish to open an official CVSS ID theoretically you could do it... 
Although i do not recall ever seeing one.

For websites it does not make sense.

Probably the example might fit better in mobile apps that do not allow to use https for authentication and sharing of confidential data with the servers and the correction would force a new app revision to be available to pubilc for update. In this case should be a defect of the app.